# Why does awk print the full line when using eval?

Tags: bash, awk, eval, dpkg

I'm currently in the process of modifying a large BASH script which installs/checks a series of packages in a few different distros (mainly Redhat and Debian based).

To handle some of the differences between the distros (e.g. rpm vs dpkg, yum vs apt, etc) I'm trying to load some variables with various command strings so that the script isn't full of `if debian then this, otherwise this` statements. However it appears that `awk` doesn't like being put inside an eval statement, and I can't figure out why.

**Example**

```
# Example dpkg --list output
# ii  bash       4.1-2ubuntu3    The GNU Bourne Again SHell

dpkg --list | grep 'bash'
# Outputs bash entries in dpkg.

cmd="dpkg --list | grep 'bash'"
eval $cmd                                       
# Outputs as expected, same as above.

dpkg --list | awk '/^.i/ { print $2 }'
# Outputs as expected, a list of package names.

cmd="dpkg --list | awk '/^.i/ { print $2 }'"
eval $cmd
# Awk prints full output from dpkg for every line matching the regex.
```

In the code above, simply grepping for a given package works fine, and prints as expected, but when trying to generate a full list of package names using awk, the `print $2` appears to be ignored and simply prints the full line.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the reason:

```
cmd="dpkg --list | awk '/^.i/ { print $2 }'"
echo $cmd

Output:
dpkg --list | awk '/^.i/ { print }'
```

Escape the $ sign:

```
cmd="dpkg --list | awk '/^.i/ { print \$2 }'"
```

Comment: That was exactly it. Because it was a double-quoted string, the `$2` was being evaluated as a parameter, instead of being passed literally to awk. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

eval may evaluate $2 and replace it by its values try this (escape the $ char).

```
cmd="dpkg --list | awk '/^.i/ { print \$2 }'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You want this (gotta escape $ in awk script):

```
cmd="dpkg --list | awk '/^.i.+bash/{ print \$2 }'"
eval $cmd
```

Still I do not understand why you use `eval` in this case, it causes several problems here,
(one of which is that you apparently cannot use `/^.i.*bash/` regex (shell expands glob or passes `\` inside regex) and have to resolve to `/^.i.+bash/`.

Comment: The example given was just a simplified version of what I was trying to do. Basically I have a lot of different conditions that dictate which command I need to run (various package manager checks etc), and to save putting lots of `if... elif... else` conditions in my code, I'm just loading the required commands into variables, making the rest of the code OS agnostic and easier to maintain using the variables.